# Cant update multi picklist on a workflow?

Tags: workflow, picklist

Cant update multi picklist on a workflow?  I'm assuming you cant?  And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is workflow limitation of Salesforce, You can not update multiple picklist values through workflow. There is already [**IDEA**](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bpd7AAC) posted on salesforce community, you can vote for it. Other alternative you can use trigger to update the multi picklist values.